# rspec XOR should include

Tags: ruby, rspec, xor

I want to check for the presence of exactly one of two possible strings in my rspec test (XOR).

Something to the effect of this:

```
it "worked" do
  ( 
    foo.bar.should include "A" AND foo.bar.should_not include "B" 
    ||
    foo.bar.should include "B" AND foo.bar.should_not include "A" 
  )
  # => if the above is false rspec should complain
end
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
expect(foo.bar & ['A', 'B']).to have(1).item
```

This solution takes the array, intersects it with the possible values, and makes sure that only one element (either `'A'` or `'B'`) is left.

@steenslag's answer fails because when rspec expectations fail, they stop the test, so "two falses don't make a true"...

If you want to use the old `should` syntax, it would look like this:

```
(foo.bar & ['A', 'B']).should have(1).item
```

Comment: didn't know expect().to was even a valid syntax replacement for .should, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`xor` is `^`.

```
foo.bar.should(include "A") ^ foo.bar.should(include "B")
```

Returns true when foo.bar includes either "A" or "B", but not both.

```
ar = ["AC","BC", "AB", "CC"]
ar.each{|str|p str.include?("A") ^ str.include?("B")}   
#true
#true
#false
#false
```

Comment: Is it possible that the (foo.bar.should[_not] include) statements/method calls are throwing the errors, and not the <it "worked" do end> block?

Comment: `^`on fixnum is bitwise, but it is also defined on Trueclass and FalseClass. (Example added). Note the first version cointained a mistake and was edited by me within 5 minutes.

Comment: Yeah that doesn't work, the error message I get I think insinuates that rspec doesn't care about the truthiness of the overall statement but the truthiness of each statement in the block:

Comment: Failure/Error: (foo.bar.should include "A") ^ (foo.bar.should include "B")
expected "A" to include "B"